# Change type of base class variable in controlled situation?

Tags: c++, class, casting, borland-c++

Suppose:

```
class A 
{
public:
A *Parent;
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
B *BParent;
};
```

but both 'Parent' and 'BParent' in A and B need to occupy the same memory space !
The BParent in B 'is' in fact an A, but for all B objects the parent always is a B as well, and it makes it easier to access B-only functions and variables, without the need to cast Parent to B all the time in all B and from B inheriting classes and without the need to have everything virtualized in A that may be needed in B.

Is this possible ?
Following obviously doesn't work, but is there something similar that **does** work ?

```
class B : public A
    {
    protected:
    union {
      A::Parent ;
      B *BParent;
      };
    };
```

I'd rather avoid:

```
class A
{
public:
union {
  A *Parent ;
  class B *BParent ;
  };
};
```

which would work.  I would use this latter method if there is a way to make BParent private in A and still access it in B, so that it's hidden to all non-B objects that inherit from A.

Comment: Not clear with what you are trying to achieve. May be adding constructors and sample `main()` would help understand.

Comment: @rockoder, Simply put, downcast a variable in a child object (and its children)

Comment: Virtuals are a good thing.  Your avoiding virtuals is making simple code complicated.

Comment: @brianbeuning, I'm trying to make a change to existing code without rewriting too much of it.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're asking for but here's a go.

I'm guessing you want to save some sort of access to the parent which is inherited but works for the derived types.. Maybe you're looking for this:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
private:
    T *parent;
};

class B : public A<B>
{

};
```

But it also seems like you want to preserve that A and the B...

So maybe what you're really looking for is this:

```
class A
{
protected:
    A *AParent() { return parent; }
protected:
    A *parent;
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    B *BParent() { return (B*)parent; };
};
```

Note that if you want to use the same memory for both then they must be the same. Simply casting the pointers should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks.  I considered both methods as well but as I'm working on existing code I would like to limit the changes involved.  That's why I was looking for a quick fix, which I realize may not exist, but it doesn't hurt to ask.  The template change would have a too high impact.  The function-instead-of-variable solution is a viable option but I'd rather avoid making the change, unless this is the only solution available.  But if I need to make this change I might as well simply use ((B*)Parent)->xyz wherever I need to access Parent in B and its children.